# Function for levenshtein distance calculations

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I created a function to go calculate the Levenshtein distance (L.distance) of two variables in python when using the Levenshtein package.  However, I'm getting a TypeError ("distance expected two Strings or two Unicodes") when I try to apply the function.  However, both variables I'm using to calculate the L.distance are strings.

I've tried a for loop, then took it out after looking at other script online which implement the L.distance. I created a test dataframe that only uses single words compared against each other, since I thought that could potentially be the issue (I'm comparing company names that may have many words rather than just singular words)

```
lst=['bear', 'tomato', 'green', 'snake']
lst2 =['baear', 'tomato', 'grean', 'snake']
dftest=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst,lst2)), columns =['lst1', 'lst2'])

result= []
def distancefinder(string1, string2):
    for string1, string2 in something:
        stringdist = lv.distance(string1, string2)
        result.append(stringdist)
    return (result)
dftest['lv_matchscore'] = distancefinder(dftest.lst1, dftest.lst2)
```

The expected output is the calculated L.distance of the two variables.

Comment: Can your provide example values for `string1` & `string2`?

Comment: Are `dftest.lst1` and `dftest.lst2` strings, or list of strings?

Comment: `distance expected two Strings or two Unicodes` because you are passing two `Series`

Comment: It looks like you're passing the entire Pandas series into `distancefinder()`, rather than the strings they contain. Have you tried `dftest['lv_matchscore'] = [distancefinder(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in zip(dftest['lst1'], dftest['lst2])]`?

Comment: Format code by starting the line with four spaces.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: They're not lists.  They're `pandas.Series`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting ... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: ok, I'm getting from your comments that I need to throw my for loop back in there. But I'm still getting errors. I know it's because I need an "in" statement, but when dealing with 2 variables that are separate, not sure what the " in" would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way you should do it:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import Levenshtein as lv

lst=['bear', 'tomato', 'green', 'snake']
lst2 =['baear', 'tomato', 'grean', 'snake']
dftest=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst,lst2)), columns =['lst1', 'lst2'])

result= []
def distancefinder(lst1, lst2):
    # Create the list you will populate with the results
    results = []
    # Loop through your records (Levenshtein uses strings, not pandas.Series)
    for i in range(len(lst1)):
        # Calculate the distance 
        stringdist = lv.distance(lst1[i], lst2[i])
        # Append the result
        results.append(stringdist)
    # Return the results list
    return results
dftest['lv_matchscore'] = distancefinder(dftest.lst1, dftest.lst2)
```

**EDIT**

`for i in range(len(lst1)):`

- `lst1` is the panda.Series you want to compare (`lst2` is the other one)
- `len(lst1)` returns the length of the series as an integer value (in this example, it evaluates to 4)
- `range(len(lst1))` (which would be `range(4)` in this case) returns a list of integers, starting from 0 and reaching 3. So: [0, 1, 2, 3]
- `for i in range(len(lst1))` would be `for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]` in this case. `i` will be used as index to get each element from the series you want to compare. In the first iteration, you will be comparint `lst1[0]` and `lst2[0]`; in the second, `lst1[1]` and `lst2[1]` and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand the "for i in range(len(lst1)):" and why you don't need to do the same for lst2, but will mull that over. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to break down the meaning of that line. If you have any other doubt, feel free to ask. Otherwise, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks! :)